# NoData strips in images downloaded from GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, nodata

I have drawn a rectangle which covers Ireland, and done the cloud removal for every band for Sentinel-2A.

Here is my code:

```js
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([ [-10.684816143380427,51.2370374026178], 
[-5.367433330880426,51.2370374026178],
[-5.367433330880426,53.49676390566743],
[-10.684816143380427,53.496763905667435],
[-10.684816143380427,51.2370374026178]
]);
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60')
//create a fuction and select the mask band
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])}
//copy the time and make the reflectance from 0 to 1
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2019-12-31')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .select('B8');
                  
// Make this list whichever bands you want to view or analyze
var imgb2 = dataset.mean()
                   .clip(geometry);     
print(imgb2)                 
Map.addLayer(imgb2, {min: 0, max:0.5,bands: ('B8')},'img',false);
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:imgb2,
  description:'sentinelb8',
  scale:10,
  region:geometry,
  maxPixels: 2782887522
});
```

When I download the images from my Drive, it often has some white strips with nodata value. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
I have attached the images of band 8 below.[image]